# How dose RoleAllowed and RunAs in EJB work?

Tags: jakarta-ee, authorization

In a security Java EE application, there are:

- 3 EJB: B1, B2 and B3
- 3 methods: m1 in B1, m2 in B2 and m3 in B3

An execution path: m1->(m2->m3). This means: m1 calls m2 and m2 calls m3.

A security configuration:

- 2 roles: student and professor
- m1 allows **student** role
- m2 allows **professor** role
- m3 allows **student** role
- B1 uses run-as **professor** role

I have 2 scenarios that: 
(1) If a user (Bob) is assigned **student** role. The execution m1->(m2->m3) called by Bob is **fail**. When I print roles of caller in each method:

- m1: student
- m2: professor

(2) If a user (Bob) is assigned **student** role and **professor** role. The execution m1->(m2->m3) called by Bob is **successful**. When I print roles of caller in each method:

- m1: student, professor
- m2: student, professor
- m3: student, professor

**QUESTION:**  In (1), why does RunAs affects to the role of Bob (caller)? But, in (2), it's not. System checks @RoleAllowed before @RunAs, Doesn't it?

Answer (score 0):

@RunAs is ignored for authenticated users.

It is intended to define the role that is applied to method calls that do not usually have an authenticated user principal such as EJB timeout methods and the `onMessage` method of message driven beans.